# Methods a subclass of HttpServlet override

Tags: java, servlets

I have read in HttpServlet documentation that

A subclass of HttpServlet must override at least one method, usually one of these:

```
doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
doPost, for HTTP POST requests
doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
doDelete, for HTTP DELETE requests
init and destroy, to manage resources that are held for the life of the servlet
getServletInfo, which the servlet uses to provide information about itself
```

What rule that helps compiler in checking that any one of the above method is overrided in subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. You (actually, the enduser) will just face a HTTP 405 *Method Not Implemented* error when requesting the servlet using a non-overridden HTTP method, because that's what the default implementation does.

Comment: What do you mean with "u" and "r"? Please try to communicate like as a professional programmer, not as a teen. English is not my native language, I may not understand all the words used in street/sms/childish talk.

Comment: sorry Mr BalusC ...I mean Thanks for your answer

Comment: Ah okay. You're welcome. I guessed it as "thanks for you are answer", but it made no utter sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

All of those methods are `protected`. The compiler can't require that the subclass override "at least one of them".

It just wouldn't make sense not to, because you would have a "not implemented explosion" servlet.

Comment: Can u explain wht is mean by not implemented explosion

Comment: The abstract class has implementations for all of these methods that throw NotImplementedExceptions if they are called (ie if you do not override them)